# How do I add a node to a frame using python

Tags: scripting, node-editor

I have a frame node and a couple of other nodes.

I want to add the nodes to the frame.

I can't find any examples of how to do this.

```
frame = nodes.new(type='NodeFrame')
glass = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfGlass')
trans = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfTransparent')
```

frame.nodes does not seem to exist so not sure.  Do I have to append to something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution as shown below and thought I would post the answer to help others facing the same problem.  It is actually more obvious than I first thought.

```
glass.parent = frame
trans.parent = frame
```

Comment: Could you please mark the question as solved?