# How to put Nodes inside NodeFrame in python?

Tags: python

How to put `Nodes` inside `NodeFrame`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Have a look into: [How do I add a node to a frame using python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75677/how-do-i-add-a-node-to-a-frame-using-python) (possible duplicate)

All you have to do is assigning the frame node to the `parent` property of each node: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Node.html#bpy.types.Node.parent

[image]

Example for all nodes in selection based on Templates -> Python -> Operator Node:

```
import bpy

def main(operator, context):
    space = context.space_data
    node_tree = space.node_tree
    
    frame = node_tree.nodes.new(type='NodeFrame')
    for n in context.selected_nodes:
        n.parent = frame

class NodeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "node.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Node Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        space = context.space_data
        return space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR'

    def execute(self, context):
        main(self, context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NodeOperator)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NodeOperator)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```